# Data loss on View Class, when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When ever I click on textField and key board appears, my list of data i.e coming from API is vanashing,

```
import SwiftUI
import ExytePopupView

struct Wallet: View {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var walltetVM = ShopViewModel()
    @State var showShopDetails: Bool = false
    @State var openShowDetails: Bool = false
    @State var selectedShopId:String = ""
    @State var selectedCouponDetail: CouponModel?

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Search view
                VStack{
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                .foregroundColor(AppColors.semiBlue)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                            
                                .padding()
                        }
                        
                        
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            if searchText.isEmpty {
                                Text(MaggnetLocalizedString(key: "Restaurant, Beauty shop...", comment: ""))
                                    .foregroundColor(AppColors.blackWhite)
                                    .font(Font(AppFont.lightFont(lightFontWithSize: 15)))
                            }
                            TextField("", text: $searchText)
                                .font(Font(AppFont.regularFont(regularFontWithSize: 15)))
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(AppColors.blackWhite)
                        .padding(.horizontal,10)
                        .padding(.leading,-15)
                        
                        Divider()
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Image("places")
                                
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal,20)
                            .padding(.leading,-12)
                        }
                        
                    }
                .frame(height: 45)
                .background(AppColors.fadeBackground)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical,10)
            
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    VStack{
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination:ShopDetail(shopId:self.selectedShopId)
                            .environmentObject(walltetVM),
                                       isActive: $openShowDetails) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }.hidden()
                        
                        Points()
                        
                        ForEach(0..<walltetVM.finalsCouponList.count,id: \.self){
                            index in
                        VStack{
                            
                            // SHOP LIST HEADERS
                            HStack{
                                Text(walltetVM.finalsCouponList[index].name)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    .font(Font(AppFont.mediumFont(mediumFontWithSize: 15)))
                                    .foregroundColor(AppColors.blackWhite)
                                    .padding(.horizontal,10)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                Button {
                                } label: {
                                    Text(MaggnetLocalizedString(key: "viewAll", comment: ""))
                                        .font(Font(AppFont.regularFont(regularFontWithSize: 12)))
                                        .foregroundColor(AppColors.blackWhite)
                                        .padding()
                                        .frame(height: 27, alignment: .center)
                                        .background(AppColors.fadeBackground)
                                        .cornerRadius(8)
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                            
                            
                            // MAIN SHOP LIST
                            
                            VStack{
                                ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
                                    HStack{
                                        ForEach(0..<walltetVM.finalsCouponList[index].couopons.count,id: \.self){
                                            indeX in
                                            Shops(coupons: walltetVM.finalsCouponList[index].couopons[indeX])
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    selectedShopId = walltetVM.finalsCouponList[index].couopons[indeX].businessId?.description ?? ""
                                                    print(selectedShopId)
                                                    selectedCouponDetail = walltetVM.finalsCouponList[index].couopons[indeX]
                                                    showShopDetails = true
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                            .padding(.top,-5)
                            
                         }
                        .padding(.top,-5)

                        }
                    }
                }
                .blur(radius: showShopDetails ? 3 : 0)
                .popup(isPresented: $showShopDetails, autohideIn: 15, dismissCallback: {
                    showShopDetails = false
                }) {
                    ShopDetailPopUp(couponDeatil: self.selectedCouponDetail)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Wallet"),displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack{
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image("wishIcon").frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    Button {
                    } label: {
                        
                        Image("notifIcon").frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                    }
                })
                
                .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
            }
            .onAppear(){
                walltetVM.getWallets()
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.openShopDetails))
                   { obj in
                       showShopDetails = false
                       openShowDetails.toggle()
                   }
            .environment(\.layoutDirection,Preferences.chooseLanguage == AppConstants.arabic ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight)

        }
    }
}

struct Wallet_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Wallet()
    }
}
```

bannerList is marked as @Published, API call working fine, but in same View class I have one search text field , when I tap on it all the data I was rendering from API get lost and disappears from list.

Comment: Please include a [mre] -- this is not enough to represent the issue.

Comment: `Wheneever I click on textField...`, there is no `TextField` in the code 
     that you show, that's probably why it does not work.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Come on, I could Not Share whole code, off course there textfield, I just gave reference of combine framework which I am using, there is everything in my code.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a joke, although since the main problem is related to tapping on the search TextField, I think 
it should be included in the code. That's when `...get lost and disappears from list.`

Comment: Does community guideline allows emojees in comment? - On the side note @ajaynegi above code does little to help us to help you, you can create a small poc, put it on GitHub and share us the link, or share a the complete view (minus business info)

Comment: Try one thing, the collection that you have binded to the list, put a breakpoint in its setter. And when you click the textField see if breakpoint hits. Quite possibly it is being cleared by some thread.

Comment: It is a code smell when you have a `ForEach` involving an `index`. The use of `tag` is also suspicious.  You don't need to post all of your code but [mcve] would help

Comment: @SaketKumar i took another screen and only put one textfield and one small API data in it just for testing and its happening again, only with textfield.

Comment: Yes, we can all keep guessing about what you are trying to do, but it would be better to just show us a 
minimal reproducible example code, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine  I hope you got the whole code, I have edited the code now please walk through and help.

Comment: @Paulw11 please look into the Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are holding a reference to your view model using `ObservedObject`:

```swift
@ObservedObject var walltetVM = ShopViewModel()
```

However, because you are creating the view model within the view, the view might tear down and recreate this at any moment, which might be why you are losing your data periodically.

If you use [`StateObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject), this ensures that SwiftUI will retain the object for as long as the view lives, so the object won't be recreated.

```swift
@StateObject var walltetVM = ShopViewModel()
```

Alternatively, you could create the view model outside of the view and inject it into the view and keep using `ObservedObject` (but you'll still need to make sure the object lives as long as the view).

Comment: thanks this worked. I really appreciate that, but can you enlightened me more for future reference, like why it get lost only when I tap on textfield.

Comment: @ajaynegi `ObservedObject` is a little weird and unpredictable when you create the object directly in the view. SwiftUI can recreate it at any time, there's no way of knowing. For future reference, you should always use `StateObject` if you are creating an `ObservableObject` model within a view.

Answer (score 0):

I found something working but still not optimised solution
instead of calling it on onAppear, I called API function in init method.

```
 init(){
        walltetVM.getWallets()
    }
```

Comment: Please share any other solution If possible, Thanks